# Cocoapods 1.3.1 + XPC Service

Tags: cocoapods, xpc

Until version 1.2.1, XPC service targets worked fine with cocoapods, but with updating to 1.3.1, I get the following error:

`[!] Unable to find host target(s) for Renderer. Please add the host targets for the embedded targets to the Podfile.
Certain kinds of targets require a host target. A host target is a "parent" target which embeds a "child" target. These are example types of targets that need a host target:
- Framework
- App Extension
- Watch OS 1 Extension
- Messages Extension (except when used with a Messages Application)`

The relevant podspec lines are:

`target 'Renderer' do
    project 'Renderer/Renderer.xcodeproj'
    platform :osx, '10.10'
    pod 'HTMLKit', :git => 'https://github.com/iabudiab/HTMLKit.git'
end`

Any suggestions?

I tried putting this target as the child of my primary target but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned here: https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/6256, you need to specify your XPC service as a target dependency in your primary project.